# Querying a group chat table by participants in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a chat app which like a typical chat app, gets conversations a user is involved in (single and group chats). The structure is like this: every conversation has a participantsIDs (which is a string of userIds that participate in that particular group chat - using string because array cannot be used as PK or SK). And I query all conversations where the participantsIDs field contains the currently logged in user, and that fetches the appropriate conversations.

The problem is I cannot use contains in the query because I get an error

> Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: contains

I cannot use scan because that is obviously discouraged and slow.

Is there another solution to this seemingly common problem or is my noSQL db design bad and typically there is a better way to design this query in noSQL databases?

I've tried:

- Using Scan - again bad for performance so scratched that
- Querying with `contains` - this leads to error

  > Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: contains

I've run out of ideas, but i have a feeling this may be a bad noSQL database design issue?

My Conversations Data Model:

```
  "conversationID": {
    "S": "convo-100"
  },
  "lastMessageDate": {
    "N": "1704135199949"
  },
  "dateCreated": {
    "N": "1704135199949"
  },
  "lastMessageText": {
    "S": "why\n"
  },
  "lastSenderID": {
    "S": "0ac8d855-34ed-4173-a40c-810ba7702a80"
  },
  "participantsIDs": {
    "S": "userid-100 userid-101"
  },
  "type": {
    "S": "single"
  },
  "unreadMessageCount": {
    "N": "0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use contains on the partition or sort key of an item, but you can use contains on non key attributes.

It's difficult to recommend a solution without knowing your data model and access patterns. But I'd have an item for each user in a group/conversation.

Then you can use a GSI to easily get all groups/conversations a user belongs to in a single Query request.

Comment: "But I'd have an item for each user in a group/conversation." - What do you mean exactly by that?

Comment: Without knowing your data model it's difficult to suggest as I said, but you should have an item in your table for every unique user in a conversation/group.

Comment: So you're suggesting i create a conversation item for each user in a conversation and use the same conversationID as PK and the userId as the SK? I'll have to update n documents everytime a conversation is modified, that's hard to manage.

Comment: You have to add/remove 1 item everytime a user joins or leaves a group

Comment: that i understood. But the big issue is modifying the same attributes across 10 items when there are 10 participants, things like lastMessage, lastUpdated, etc. Any efficient solution/workaround?

Comment: Those should be separate items and shouldn't hold that information. Your data model needs revising.